# Remove the space from infront of my C String

Tags: c, string

I have some code that outputs like this:

```
void exec_prompt(char * usr_name, char * host_name)
{
    printf(" %s::%s\n", usr_name, host_name);
    return;
}
```

But the print out doesnt look as expected:

```
 geisst::ALPHA-DT2
```

There is that space at the front of the string.

The usr_name variable is passed from the main function and is returned from the getenv() function. The host_name variable is passed from the main function with the use of the following function:

```
char * returnHost()
{
    char hostname[1024];
    hostname[1023] = '\0';
    gethostname(hostname, 1023);

    return hostname;
}
```

Maybe the getenv() function adds a space?

Any help or advice is appreciated and please be nice :P

GeissT

Comment: Sorry if it is offensive, but is it not just a space between `"` and `%s` in `printf(" %s`?

Comment: you do have a space in the string right there: `" %s::%s\n"`

Comment: Holy wow. Didn't even notice that....

I am so freaking embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your format has a space: " %s::%s\n"

Just change it to:

```
printf("%s::%s\n", usr_name, host_name);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy,

So embarrassed, can't believe I missed it.